# How can I force all the equations in a document to refresh in the LyX editor?

Tags: lyx

Often I'll use Ctrl+scroll wheel to zoom the text to a different size but this doesn't affect the size of equations that have already been entered (though new equations get rendered at a size that corresponds to the text zoom level at the time they are edited). Is there some command that will force all the equations in a document to get re-rendered at the right size for the current zoom level?

I'm using LyX 2.0.3, if that matters. Thanks!

Comment: I can't seem to reproduce this, running on Win7/32bit, LyX 2.0.3. What's your platform?

Comment: Linux (Ubuntu 11.10), 64-bit.

Comment: If you are talking about instant previews(Look and Feel -> Display -> Instant Preview) then dynamic rendering is not yet there in Lyx 2.0.3. I usually reopen the document to render it at some zoom level.